# how to make iPhone app crash after launch?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash

What is the code on Xcode and where do I put it to make an iOS app crash?
I want to make my app launch a url and then crash.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: simple exit(0). 0 is a status code which means successful termination.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a terrible idea, but if you insist you can just call a method that doesn't exist to force a crash, e.g.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doesntExist:)];
```

Or you can close the App like this:

```
exit(0);
```

But you really shouldn't do this, neither of these methods are acceptable for the App Store (or anything for that matter!)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to crash (in order to see how your app recovers from a crash), simply do something stupid like `[nameOfArray objectAtIndex:100000000];`

Comment: Division by zero doesn't crash. You simply get a `NaN` result.

Comment: My bad, fixed now :-)